# Can anyone explain what is happening in this bit of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking through a jQuery smooth-scrolling tutorial, and trying to figure out how it worked, when I hit this line of code:

```
 $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
```

I can't figure out what it does. It looks like the guy is assigning a string to a variable, but it also kinda looks like he's testing that variable. And I don't understand the use of && and || here. Can anybody explain this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Wow! What a response! This is taking a bit for me to understand, though - I will have to print this out or something and work on it. Once I understand what's going on, I'll be able to pick the answer that helped me the most. In particular, this bit:

```
if ($target.length && $target) {
$target = $target;
```

is stymying me. How does the program know to assign $target to $target? Does the operation assign $target to the first reference to itself (the left side of the equals sign), or to the second reference to itself (the right side, after the &&)?

Comment: I've already upvoted what I thought was the best answer, but there's also a problem with his logic. You want to check if $target is not NULL before checking $target.length. The expression would actually be better expressed as a ternary operation.

Comment: @Gopherkhan I get the feeling `$target` is guaranteed to be a jQuery object

Comment: *updated comment*  If it's guaranteed to be an jquery object, then the ternary option makes even more sense. It's more concise and readable to say $target = $target.length ? $target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']'); for this case. And since $foo is still a valid name in raw js, if it's not guaranteed to be a jquery object, the potential for error is there. Better to be defensive, I'd say.

Comment: @StormShadow To explain it using simple words, the program checks if ((`$target.length` is not [`undefined`, `null`, any falsy value] AND `$target.length > 0`) AND (`$target` is not [`undefined`, `null`, any falsy value])) THEN (assign `$target` to itself(the already existing reference of `$target`)) ELSE (assign `$target` to `$('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']')`)

Comment: Thanks Narendra - that really clarified it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a cryptic(or elegant?) version of the equivalent ternary operator

```
$target = ($target.length && $target) ? $target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
```

This ternary and the original short circuit expression will return exactly same values if the evaluation of $target does not change the value of $target. But if the evaluation of $target changes the value of $target then SCE and ternary returns different values e.g.

```
var a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
a && ++b || c
returns 3;
//resetting b
b = 2
a && ++b ? ++b : c 
returns 4;
```

If the evaluation of $target changes the value of $target then the equivalent ternary operator for the SCE `$target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');` would be the following

```
$target = ($result= ($target.length && $target)) ? $result : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
```

Comment: Fun fact: Before Python had the equivalent of the ternary operator, most people used `and` and `or` like in the JavaScript snippet in the question.

Comment: That is not correct. JavaScript does not implicitly evaluate logical operations to boolean values.

Comment: I never said Javascript evaluates to boolean values. I just wrote a equivalent expression because OP asked for a easy explanation. Can you give a example where my expression and OP's expression will give a different value.

Comment: @Narendra Just because your expression and the OP's result in the same answer does not mean they are equivalent. I take issue with the `($target.length && $target)` in your explanation as it is incorrect.

Comment: I clearly gave you the example why this is wrong. a = true; b =false; c=233; d = a ? b : c will set d to false and the OP's expression will set d to 233 ...the correct ternary is -- a && b ? b : c

Answer (score 4):

It's testing `$target` (which I assume is a jQuery object) for elements and if empty, assigning a default value.

See [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for a detailed explanation.

### Update

To explain (in case you don't feel like reading the MDN docs), JavaScript logical comparison operators work left-to-right.

```
expr1 && expr2
```

This will return `expr1` if it can be converted to `false`; otherwise, returns `expr2`

```
expr1 || expr2
```

This will return `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`

To break down the line in question, think of it this way

```
$target = ($target.length && $target) || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
```

Looking at the first operation...

```
$target.length && $target
```

This will return `$target.length` if `$target.length` can be converted to `false` (ie `0`), otherwise it will return `$target`.

The second operation looks like this...

```
(operation1) || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']')
```

If the result of the `operation1` can be converted to `true` (ie `$target`), then it will be returned, otherwise `$('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']')`.

Comment: I've seen this syntax a bit too.  Why doesn't this statement evaluate to a boolean?

Comment: Actually it should be -- if ($target.length && $target) {$target = $target;} else {$target = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');} . I cannot think of a situation where $target.length is true and $target is false but still it is the precise translation.

Comment: @Narendra That is incorrect. Please read the MDN document linked in my answer

Comment: Your translation is clearly wrong. Look at this example 
a = true;
b = false;
c = 233;
d = a&&b || c
//returns 233  Whereas your expression returns false

Comment: @Narendra no, my expression also returns 233. `a && b || c == (a && b) || c == false || c == c`

Comment: I am referring to the if else on the top. It returns false. See the if else expansion given by Omeid or MTönnberg

Comment: @Narendra I see. I've removed the incorrect `if .. else` block.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Short Circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and its *not* equivalent of ternary operator.

and your peace of code equivalent is following:

```
if ($target.length && $target) {
    $target = $target;
} 
 else {
    $target = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
}
```

In JavaScript and most of other loosely-typed languages which have more than the two truth-values True and False, the value returned is based on *last value*.

`a && b` will return a if it false, else will return b.

`a || b` will return a if true, else b.

to better understand last value look at the following examples:

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = 5;
var d = 0;

return a && b; //returns false
return a && c; //returns 5
return b && c; //returns false
return c && b; //returns false
return c && a; //returns true;
return d && b; //returns 0;
return b && d; //returns false;

return a || b; //returns true
return a || c; //returns true
return b || c; //returns 5
return c || b; //returns 5
return c || a; //returns 5;
return d || b; //returns false;
return b || d; //returns 0;
```

#### Update:

Ternary operator:

`(condition)?(evaluate if condition was true):(evaluate if condition was false)`

Short Circuit Evaluation:

`(evaluate this, if true go ahead else return this) && (evaluate this, if true go ahead else return this)`

You can clearly see that there is a `condition` for ternary operator while in SCE the evaluation of value itself is the condition.

Comment: I dont think what you gave is the equivalent expression. Did you try $a&&$b||$c ...it returns 5 not false.

Comment: it returns the last value, so it should be 5. what do you think is wrong about it ?

Comment: If you substitute $a,$b and $c in your if else expansion it will return false..not 5

Comment: The if else expansion of MTönnberg is the right expansion. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I think the if else is in turn exactly equivalent to the ternary operator. Can you please explain by example how your if else is different from  the ternary operator -- $target = ($target.length && $target) ? $target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

Comment: there is no doubt, `ternary operator` is same as `if-else` at least in practice, but the `Short-Circuit` is not not equivalent of ternary operator.

Comment: i agree that a && b is different from a ? b : c but i am not sure how (a&&b) || c is different from a && b ? b : c ...except that in the ternary the expression b might be evaluated twice.

Comment: because that can be written as a&&b ? a : c or anything else, a&&b ? d : c

Comment: I dont think a&&b || c will ever return a ...it will either return b or c ...the same is true with the ternary a&&b?b:c

Comment: That is not the issue. Something is equivalent when you can can transform them from one to another. you can never write a ? b :c in Short-Circuit evaluation.

Comment: Agreed..ternary is more powerful than SCE. I updated my answer the ternary will return exactly same value as SCE but number of times b gets evaluated is different in both the expressions a&&b || c evaluates b only once whereas a&&b ? b : c evaluates b twice. Please let me know if there is any other difference.

Answer (score 0):

> $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

In javascript you can make inline comparisons when assigning a variable so the example you is the equivalent to

```
if($target.length && $target)
    $target = $target;
else
    $target = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
```

for more examples, see http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_comparisons.asp
for example:

```
var x= y > 4 ?value1:value2
```

Witch means that if condition is true (y is greater than 4), x will be assigned value1 otherwise it will be assigned value2